# Two very similar apps, with different texts and UI graphics

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, design-patterns, app-store

I'm going to developer two very similar apps, the logic is absolutely the same, but api calls base URLs, texts and UI graphics( such as backgrounds etc) will be different, but the all views will be the same (buttons, labels in the same places). It's quizes apps.

How to do it in the smart way? To not duplicate code etc.

I thought about to setup workspace, add bundles with UI, plists with texts and URL's, and than based on project name or identifier use one of the bundles, etc.

Maybe somebody can share smth else? More efficient way.

Thx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I thought about [...] adding bundles with UI, plists texts and URL's

You wrote your own answer. Additionally you setup two targets. One for each project. Within the target you define an envorinment variable, which you can use in your code to switch between the bundles / URLs.

You should write a Helper Class to get the Ressources. That helper class checks the environment variable and gives back the correct ressource.

(You may want to write categories for `UIImage` and `NSURL` and write your own `NSLocalizedString` version. With that you don't need to check any conditions/settings anywhere else in your code.)